Unable to publish Jupyter Notebook to Medium
I'm trying to publish an article from a Jupyter Notebook to Medium using the jupyter_to_medium package. My jupyter notebook version is 6.1.5.
Whenever trying to uploading using the following code:
import jupyter_to_medium as jtm 

jtm.publish(r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\people_analytics_HR_attrition_rate.ipynb",
    integration_token=None,
    pub_name=None,
    title=None,
    tags=None,
    publish_status='draft',
    notify_followers=False,
    license='all-rights-reserved',
    canonical_url=None,
    chrome_path=None,
    save_markdown=False,
    table_conversion='chrome')

I keep getting this error message below:
Failed to post to Medium
Returned error message below

"JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File \"C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\requests\\models.py\", line 971, in json
return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File \"C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\Lib\\json\\__init__.py\", line 346, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File \"C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\Lib\\json\\decoder.py\", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File \"C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\Lib\\json\\decoder.py\", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError(\"Expecting value\", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File \"C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\jupyter_to_medium\\_bundler.py\", line 37, in upload
data = publish(**kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File \"C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\jupyter_to_medium\\_publish_to_medium.py\", line 300, in publish
p.main()
File \"C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\jupyter_to_medium\\_publish_to_medium.py\", line 216, in main
self.author_id = self.get_author_id()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File \"C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\jupyter_to_medium\\_publish_to_medium.py\", line 96, in get_author_id
return r.json()['data']['id']
^^^^^^^^
File \"C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\requests\\models.py\", line 975, in json
raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Image of Error Received
I have followed the steps in the article here https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-to-medium/ and have my integration token in the home directory.

It seems that whatever you are putting into comlexjson is not a json formatted value (since the first char is not properly formatted with double quotes). What does your code look like?

error "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) means you have empty JSON

@AndrewRyan this is how the code looks like:
import jupyter_to_medium as jtm
jtm.publish(r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\people_analytics_HR_attrition_rate.ipynb",
integration_token=None,
pub_name=None,
title=None,
tags=None,
publish_status='draft',
notify_followers=False,
license='all-rights-reserved',
canonical_url=None,
chrome_path=None,
save_markdown=False,
table_conversion='chrome'
)

@furas, how do I fix the empty JSON issue?

Is the path to your file correct?

it looks like server sends empty JSON - and you can't change it. Maybe Medium changes some functions and now it needs changes in module. But this is task for author of this module. You may send problem to author. Or you may try to debug module and fix code.

@AndrewRyan, yes. the file path is correct.
